# Looking for Samples of Canadian West Coast Accent

Tags: accent

If this is not the right place to ask, then feel free to redirect me to a more appropriate site.

A long time ago I learned English in British Columbia and adopted the local accent. Since I am immersed in a more British-English speaking environment I long lost it, or even the ability to use it on purpose.

Could you please recommend any movies or audio-books, that could help me get it back into my ear? The more the better.

Thank you very much

Comment: The [CBC news](http://www.cbc.ca/listen/) is generally spoken in standard Canadian English accent, which is [not much different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_English) from the West Coast Canadian English accent.

Comment: Probably belongs on meta.